# How would you use a `for` or `while` loop to find the nth word in a sentence

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

How would you use a `for` or `while` loop to find a word in a sentence if the user enter like inputs inputs the sentence and the index of the word in the sentence.

```py
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
word_number = input ('Please enter word number request: ')
```

Comment: There is no need of for/while loop,here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that the best option is https://stackoverflow.com/a/62420371/2399444
But it looks like is a requirement for you use `For` or `While`

For instance one solution could be

```
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
word_number = input('Please enter word number request: ')
words = sentence.split(' ')

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if(i == word_number-1):
        print(word)
        break
if(word_number > len(words)):
    print('Word not found. Sentence only has', len(words), 'words')
```

Comment: Python syntax accepts the use of parenthesis on `if` statements, but they aren't required  as they are on other languages, like `php` for example. `if i == word_number-1:`  and `if word_number > len(words):` are both correct if statements and imo more readable. For these, and several other reasons,  which I cannot fully explain due to the limit of comments charterers,  this answer shouldn't not have been accepted as correct.

Comment: @CONvid19I I disagree with  you, you are right  when you said that parenthesis aren't  strictly required in python,  but good developers strive to write code that is clear and correct . Furthermore, extra parentheses, just like indentations, whitespace, and other style standards, help visually organize the code in a logical way. On other hand I would like to know the other reasons in order to learn more. To finish in my question I remark that the best question is the another, but not answer exactly the question I just try to complete the answer

Comment: I don't find your code readable, but that's just my opinion and obviously you can use what suits your coding style better if you're coding for yourself. You should use `if(word_number > len(words)):` at the top of the script to avoid running unnecessary code. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

```
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
word_number = input('Please enter word number request: ')
words = sentence.split(' ')
try:
    # make sure to convert to integer
    # -1 because list indices are 0-based
    print(words[int(word_number)-1])
except IndexError:
    print('Word not found. Sentence only has', len(words), 'words')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That worked. Is it possible to get the same results using a for or while loop?

Comment: You're right @CONvid19, but I wanted to show the explicit use of the `split` function where you're able to provide the character of which to split since the OP is new to the language.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why is the split no necessary? What could you do if you don't use split?

Comment: Split's default separator is a space, which is what I believe @CONvid19 is saying. When there is a space present in the string being split and no arg is given between the parenthesis the space will be defaulted to. When a string doesn't have a space it'll default to slicing character-by-character. Example `'abc'.split()` would result in `['a','b','c']`

Comment: So could you technically split the words in the sentence without using split?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder exactly.